# Multiple checks but still SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python-3.x

I have checked on this string multiple times to ensure that the (".") are in place, but the message

```
File "<ipython-input-13-ef09f7b4583b>", line 48 plt.savefig("C:\scratch\\data\"+str(angle).zfill(3)+".")

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

still comes up.

Any suggestions?

```
if save is not False:
    plt.savefig("C:\scratch\\data\"+str(angle).zfill(3)+".png")
    plt.close("all")
else:
    plt.show()

return
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python string can not terminate with `\` as this will escape the closing `"` (or `'`).

You have several options:

- Use double-back slashes in a constant manner:

  ```
  plt.savefig("C:\\scratch\\data\\" + str(angle).zfill(3) + ".png")
  ```
- Use `.format`, preferably with combination of raw string to avoid problems in case a directory name starts with `t`, `n` or any other character that will become a control sequence when prefixed with `\`:

  ```
  plt.savefig(r"C:\scratch\data\{}.png".format(str(angle).zfill(3)))
  ```